# Zoom by pinch gone in my Street Views with API version 3.53.10

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I have been using Javascript API on my web site without specifying exact version or channel, so it's supposed to be weekly channel by default, I guess. A few days ago I noticed that I cannot zoom by pinch in StreetView mode in Chrome on my Android devices anymore (after ~6 years of trouble-free pinch zooming). The zoom control (+/-) is there and works but I am really used to pinch zooming.
It only stopped working in the StreetView mode, it works fine with the map itself. It also works fine if I open the same panorama in a separate maps.google.com window, without using the API.

My first thought was to go see the API release notes. I checked the API version I am getting and it's 3.53.10 which is not even listed in the release notes section - the last one I see there is 3.53.7, so no clues in the release notes about what could have been changed.
Switching the version to 3.52 fixed the problem for now but it will not work forever.
What's going on? Does anybody have the same problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue. And if you believe it is an API bug, open a new bug in their issue tracker.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/290641653

Answer (score 0):

Google confirmed the bug in 3.53 and [fixed it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/290641653) in 3.53.11.